# How to add both NAME and NUMBER description on Geo Pandas plot in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, geopandas, annotate

I try to create a map in GeoPandas in Python.

And I use below code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (20,10))
 
dane_mapa_woj.plot(column='liczba_logowan_w_wojewodztwie', ax=ax, cmap='YlOrRd', linewidth=0.8, edgecolor='gray', legend = True)

#dane_mapa_woj.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x.NUMBER, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center', color = "black"), axis=1)
dane_mapa_woj.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x.NAME, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center', color = "black"), axis=1)

ax.axis('off')
 
plt.show()
```

And my picture shows like below:

[image]

As you can see I have descriptions of each territoru by code:     `dane_mapa_woj.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x.NAME, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center', color = "black"), axis=1)`

Nevertheless I would like to have both NAME and NUMBER on my plot, but when I use bothe these codes:

```
dane_mapa_woj.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x.NUMBER, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center', color = "black"), axis=1)
dane_mapa_woj.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x.NAME, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center', color = "black"), axis=1)
```

I have a strong mess on my picture:

[image]

My question is: how can I manage the position of NAME and NUMBER descriptions on the plot? Could you change my code to decrease this mess? I would like to have something like for example:

POMORSKIE

5742

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a new line command:

```py
dane_mapa_woj.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x.NAME +'\n' + x.NUMBER, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center', color = "black", weight='semibold'), axis=1)
```

Otherwise if you want to precisely locate the text, look into shifting the text through the `xytext` and `textcoords` parameters of [ax.annotate()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html)

```py
dane_mapa_woj.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x.NAME, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], xytext=(0,0), textcoords='offset pixels', ha='center', color = "black", weight='semibold'), axis=1)
dane_mapa_woj.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x.NUMBER, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], xytext=(0,10), textcoords='offset pixels', ha='center', color = "black", weight='semibold'), axis=1)
```

Comment: great, I gave best answer! An one more thing, maybe you know how to also thicker font of NAME and NUMBER ?

Comment: You can pass further keyword arguments to `ax.annotate()` that format the text (see detailed information [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)). To get bolder text you can add either `weight='bold'` or `weight='semibold'` or adjust the fontsize `fontsize=10` and so on after the `color='black'` argument.